# To compare 2 list and get the not matching items in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2 lists and the input looks like `list1=["car", "boat", "sun", "ride"]` and `list2=["car_1", "car_2", sun_3"]`. My expected output should be like `output=["boat", "ride"]`.
My code snippet for your reference:

```
For i in list1:
   If any( i in e for e in list2):
      Print (i)
```

My code is not looping through the list1. Please Correct me what i am missing.

Comment: @ThePyGuy because my list2 doesnt have the keyword of boat and ride.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use List-Comprehension, then check for partial string in each item of list2 for each value in list1:

```py
output=[v for v in list1 if not any(v in x for x in list2)]
print(output)
['boat', 'ride']
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your code will work with one modification: insert `not` before `any()`. To construct a list `output`, replace the `print()` statement with `output.append(i)` where `output` is initialized before the loop as `output = []`.

There is an alternative approach that optimizes for a more restricted type of matching. Assuming `list2` contains only strings of the form `prefix + '_' + suffix` where `prefix` and `suffix` do not contain `_`, and also assuming we are to keep items in `list1` unless they exactly match a `prefix` found in `list2`, you can do it this way:

```py
prefSet = {x.split('_')[0] for x in list2}
print( [x for x in list1 if x not in prefSet] )
```